# Randomized Submatrix of a Sparse Matrix

Tags: probability, matrices, random-variables, random, expected-value

I have a sparse square matrix $A$ with size $n \times n$ and number of nonzero entries $nnz$.
The goal is making a sub-matrix $B$ with $s$ nonzeros which are randomly chosen from $A$. Duplicates are ok, so we need *at most* $s$ nonzeros in $B$.

The probability of entry $A_{kl}$ being chosen is $p_{ij} = \frac{A_{ij}^2}{\sum_{k, l} A_{kl}^2}$, in which, $k$ and $l$ go through all the matrix entries. I have this algorithm in mind so far:

1. generate a random number $rand$ such that $0<= rand <= 1$.
2. if(rand < p_11) add $A_{11}$ to B.
3. go to the next entry of A and repeat from step $1$ until $s$ entries is chosen.

If I go through all entries of $A$ **once**, on average how many entries will be chosen? In other words, how many times I should go through entries of $A$ to have $s$ entries chosen? I want to change the probability $p_{ij}$ so by going through entries of A once, all $s$ entries are chosen.

Comment: In your original setup, the probability will be quite ugly to write it out. If you allow $p_{ij}$ to be a constant $p$, the number of entries chosen follows a Binomial distribution then you can calculate the value of $p$ so that the probability of choosing $s$ or more entries in $1$ run is higher than a certain probability.

Comment: @BGM The one condition that I want to have for p is "choose entries with higher values with higher probabilities". That's why I didn't use a constant p. Do you have any other suggestion for p?

Comment: For your current setup, the expected number of entries chosen per run is $1$, as the expected value of the sum of indicators is just the sum of individual probabilities. Are you require the sum of the individual probabilities has to be $1$? And can you set the probabilities arbitrarily large? Say if you set $\displaystyle p_{ij} = \frac {A_{ij}^2} {A_{ij}^2 + \varepsilon}$ then it satisfy $p_{ij}$ is increasing with $A_{ij}^2$, all zero entries are filtered out with zero probability to be chosen, and the probabilities are arbitrarily close to $1$.